# Web Extraction code needs UPDATING, Trying to add sheet from worksheet Cell

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am trying to write this line of code so it takes the sheet to use from a Sheet + cell in excel I can do it with the class and child nods, but not for the sheet to input the data Into. The code is repeated for columns A to K

I know that even this is not the best, however I am limited in VBA and it does work. I have Changed from Sheet3 to Sheet4, Also Posted Here [Mr Excel](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/web-extraction-code-needs-a-tweak.1157954/)

**Current Code that Works**

```
'Sheet20 A18 + B18
If element.getElementsByClassName(Sheets("Sheet20").Range("A18"))(Sheets("Sheet20").Range("B18")) Is Nothing Then ' Get CLASS and Child Nod
    wsSheet.Cells(Sheet4.Cells(Sheet4.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "A").Value = "-" 'If Nothing then Hyphen in CELL
Else
    HtmlText = element.getElementsByClassName(Sheets("Sheet20").Range("A18"))(Sheets("Sheet20").Range("B18")).innerText ' Get CLASS and Child Nod
    wsSheet.Cells(Sheet4.Cells(Sheet4.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "A").Value = HtmlText 'return value in column
End If
```

Current Results, still need a slight tweak in the Class and Child Nods

[image: Product Image 1]

**The NEW Changes I am trying to implement**

**Sheet4** is taken from **Cell E16 on Sheet20**. This will KEEP CHANGING depending on which tab is selected and therefore the data needs to go into the correct sheet. I will be using this code several times and rather that re-write it each time for each sheet. I want to change the input sheet within the code. This way I can change the class + child nods + sheet to add data too, thus enabling me to use the ONE code.

```
If element.getElementsByClassName(Sheets("Sheet20").Range("A18"))(Sheets("Sheet20").Range("B18")) Is Nothing Then ' Get CLASS and Child Nod
    '''#### Instead of Sheet4 I am trying to get the required sheet from SHEET20 Cell E16
    wsSheet.Cells(Sheets("Sheet20").Range("E16").Cells(Sheets("Sheet20").Range("E16").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "A").Value = "-" 'If Nothing then Hyphen
Else
    HtmlText = element.getElementsByClassName(Sheets("Sheet20").Range("A18"))(Sheets("Sheet20").Range("B18")).innerText ' Get CLASS and Child Nod
    '''#### Instead of Sheet4 I am trying to get the required sheet from SHEET20 Cell E16
    wsSheet.Cells(Sheets("Sheet20").Range("E16").Cells(Sheets("Sheet20").Range("E16").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "A").Value = HtmlText 'return value in column
```

**This is the results with the new Code**

[image: Product Picture 2]

**Problem**

Although the correct sheet is selected, ALL of the extracted data goes into the SAME cells overwriting and previous data, when it show go to next row, as show in the above image.

'##### Edit Today 2.44 uk time ######

These are the HTML classes that the code uses from sheet20, I can keep changing the classes on a button click

[image: HTML Class]

This is Sheet20 Cell E16. This will Also keep changing, what i was trying to do was get the code to use which ever sheet is stated in this cell

[image: Active Sheet]

Comment: If you start by putting those long references into shorter variables it would make reading your code a lot easier to follow. Additionally, seeing your variable declarations would give some indication of what you expect to see being passed.

Comment: QHarr, I am very limited in vba, It took me forever to right the above code, So I don't always fully understand my own code at time. That being said, what your are saying makes sense. I think it could be selecting the correct sheet as I also stated this in the code <br/> `Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
        'Set wsSheet = wb.Sheets("Sheet4")
         Set wsSheet = wb.Sheets(Sheet20.Range("E16").Value)` take sheet from here

Comment: you have changed the worksheet the wsSheet refers to. Use two different variables for the different sheets. Where are values supposed to be written to? Sheet 4 or sheet 20? Can we see a bit more of the code?

Comment: The extracted Web Data will go into Sheet4, on this occasion. I wanted to keep reusing the same code, just change the sheet and class. I can change the html class at a click and it can get the new classes from the work sheet sheet20. This bit is fine. I was tring to do the same for the changing the sheets

Comment: This would be a simple getting sheet4 from a variable which references sheet20 https://pastebin.com/WV6sHYVh. Is this what you meant?

Comment: QHarr Hopefully this is what I am looking for, I will need to test It, However you have way more experience that me and are always. I tend to just make it up as I go along. I will test this and post back later on. Thanks.

Comment: QHarr, This is super. Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Question was Answered largely By QHarr. Thanks for Your Help. I had a few minor issues, like object required and Object Variable or with block variable not defined. I was able to fix it like this

QHarr's Code

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
 
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet20").Range("E16").Value)
 
If element.getElementsByClassName(Sheets("Sheet20").Range("A18"))(Sheets("Sheet20").Range("B18")) Is Nothing Then ' Get CLASS and Child Nod
    wsSheet.Cells(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "A").Value = "-" 'If Nothing then Hyphen in CELL
Else
    HtmlText = element.getElementsByClassName(Sheets("Sheet20").Range("A18"))(Sheets("Sheet20").Range("B18")).innerText ' Get CLASS and Child Nod
    wsSheet.Cells(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "A").Value = HtmlText 'return value in column
End If
```

With my Changes, not sure why I was having the issues, but this  fixed the problem and the data is extracted fine.

```
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet 
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
         Set wsSheet = wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets("Sheet20").Range("e16").Value)
         Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet20").Range("E16").Value)

If element.getElementsByClassName(Sheets("Sheet20").Range("A18"))(Sheets("Sheet20").Range("B18")) Is Nothing Then ' Get CLASS and Child Nod
    wsSheet.Cells(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "A").Value = "-" 'If Nothing then Hyphen in CELL
Else
    HtmlText = element.getElementsByClassName(Sheets("Sheet20").Range("A18"))(Sheets("Sheet20").Range("B18")).innerText ' Get CLASS and Child Nod
    wsSheet.Cells(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "A").Value = HtmlText 'return value in column
End If
```